# Multiplying matrix columns

Tags: c, matrix

I have a matrix with n rows and 3 columns, and I should multiply row n column 2 with row n column 3.
So if I have a matrix that looks like this:

```
1 2 3

4 5 6

7 8 9
```

Then I should multiply 2 with 3, 5 with 6 and 8 with 9, and create a matrix or an array that holds results:

```
6

30

72
```

How can I do that in C?

Comment: This looks like basic C programming, you should better look at some [examples](http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c-program-examples) before you ask a question.

Comment: @Dinesh Unfortunately I didn't write the code on my computer and now I have no access to it, but I wrote a code that made an x[n][1] and an y[n][1], x is an array/matrix that has n rows but only one column, since I only need the 2nd column, and y is the same but with the numbers of the 3rd column. So I have created an x that looks like this:

2

5

8

And a y that looks like this:

3 6 9

And now that I'm writing it I might figured it out, I know it's really simple, but I'm only in my first semester of learning C or any other programming. I'll check it tomorrow when I'll have the code.

Comment: @Preno use http://ideone.com/

Answer (score 1):

Since you are interested in learning C, an outline should do :-) The output is going to be a single column vector. Input to your function is a matrix, of some dimension p x q, and two column numbers c1 and c2. You can not skin it at least two ways.

- a function that does exactly what your problem asks, iterating x[1..p][c1] and x[1..p][c2] (so loop variable will be row numbers 1..p, and multiply them, producing result[1..p]
- a function that returns a column vector from a given matrix, and then another function that does the element-wise product of two vectors as above. This jimho might be a more interesting option.

HTH